# Ubuntu 10.04 после обновления все подменю стали англоязычными

Tags: ubuntu

Как доруссифицировать Ubuntu 10.04?

Answer (score 1):

Выполни команду в терминале (копируй команду и жми интер):

Код: Выделить всё

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -f
```

И перезагрузи компьютер. Обычно помогает.Но может не получиться. Тогда cделай следующие:

Код: Выделить всё

```
sudo reinstall language-selector language-selector-common && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -f
```

Перезагрузись

Answer (score 0):

Если те подменю, которые стали английскими, реально имеют переводы в обновленных вариантах, то стоит попробовать стандартные методы локализации: [Русификация Ubuntu](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_ubuntu).